# How to change a video if within a pause range and a key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, video

For an example, I want it to change the video if paused between 2-4 seconds and if the key 'o' is pressed. I don't want it to loop the action on the second video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an initial video variable will prevent it from looping. Using the ANCI number 111 will reference the key 'o'. 'myVideo' is for your video tag id

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var initialVideo = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';

document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if ((e || window.event).keyCode === 111 && e.target.currentSrc === initialVideo ) {
        if (vid.currentTime > 2 && vid.currentTime < 4) {
            vid.setAttribute('src', "movie.mp4");
            vid.load();
        }
    }
};
```